# Public proxy WMS

Tags: wms, proxy

I'm looking to set up my own WMS proxy but before I rush off and reinvent the wheel I thought it might be a good idea to ask if anyone has heard of an existing public/commercial WMS proxy service?

If one exists what are the pros/cons of using an existing one as opposed to running my own?

I'm new to Web mapping so any advice would be helpful.

Comment: could you expand on why you want a WMS proxy?

Comment: My thinking was that I could use a proxy to improve the preformance of external WMS consumed in my application by caching/converting between coordinate systems via a proxy. If I am on the wrong track I would welcome other suggestions

Comment: Great comments!! cheers. I did some reading about Geoserver and I think you are right. The problem is I currently don't have anywhere to instal Geoserver. Are there any public or commerical sites offering this service that you can think of. Also any ideas as to how I could avoid overwhelming the remote server by pre-seeding.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can meet your needs by using  [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) with it's [WMS datastore](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html) to ingest remote WMS services and [GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/) to handle tiling and caching on your machine.

The cascading WMS layer will handle reprojection for you (if the remote server doesn't) and GeoWebCache will store the tiles as they are requested by your client (or you can pre-seed the layers but that might overwhelm the remote server).